# Passport js serializeUser & deserializeUser

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, ldap, passport.js

I have read everything on the argument but still cannot understand it. The documentation on the Passport Js web site is very vague.

I am using Passport JS with the passport-ldapauth Strategy. **I do not have a Database**. **I obviously don't want to hit the LDAP server on each request.** I would like to authenticate the user the first time on the POST `/login` route using the passport strategy with LDAP, store the user in the session and on each subsequent requests I just want to check if the user is already logged in.

I am trying to use the session but I cannot understand how to use Passport + session with the serialize/deserialize flow. *Every example I checked use a User.findOne in the deserializeUser function.*

As of now I disabled the use of the session for Passport and I am using a custom middleware where I check if `req.session.user != null`. If that's the case the user is already logged in and I hit `next()`. Otherwise redirect to login.

Here is some code (for sake of simplicity I deleted the code not related to the question):

**Passport configuration**:

```
var express = require('express'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

var app = express();

var LdapStrategyOptions = {
  server: {
    url: '<url>',
    bindDN: '<dn>',
    bindCredentials: "<pwd>",
    searchBase: '<searchBase>',
    searchFilter: '<filter>'
  }
};
passport.use(new LdapStrategy(LdapStrategyOptions));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  store: new LokiStore({autosave: false}),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
  secret: env.get("SESSION_SECRET")
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
```

**Routes**:

```
// LOGIN ROUTE
app.get('/login',
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

// LOGIN HANDLER ROUTE
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    req.session.userId = req.user.cn;
    req.session.user = {
      "userId": req.user.cn,
      "displayName": req.user.displayName
    };
  res.redirect('/');
});

// LOGOUT ROUTE
app.get('/logout',
  function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
      req.logout();
      res.redirect('/');
    });
});

// HOME ROUTE
app.get('/', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
   res.render('home');
});
```

**IsLoggedIn Middleware**:

```
var isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user != null){
    console.log("is auth ok '" + req.session.user.userId +"'");
    return next();
  }

  console.log("redirect to auth/login");
  res.redirect('/auth/login');
}
```

What am I missing? Is there any security fault in my setup? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you're missing `app.use(passport.session());`?

Comment: no. I removed it from the sample code because as I wrote, I am not using it because I cannot understand what should I write in passport.deserializeUser().

The sample cose is just the way I found to make it work with a custom session management.

Answer (score 2):

From [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure#sessions) docs:

> In a typical web application, the credentials used to authenticate a user will only be transmitted during the login request. If authentication succeeds, a session will be established and maintained via a cookie set in the user's browser.
>
> Each subsequent request will not contain credentials, but rather the unique cookie that identifies the session. In order to support login sessions, Passport will serialize and deserialize user instances to and from the session.

Basically `serializeUser` is supposed to return a unique user identifier so you can `deserializeUser` back into JSON later.

So for your implementation you should probably do something along these lines:

DISCLAIMER: I have no experience with LDAP.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  //We can identify the user uniquely by the CN,
  //so we only serialize this into the session token.
  done(null, user.cn);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(cn, done) {
  //Directly query LDAP.
  //I'm not sure passport caches the result (only calls deserializeUser for new sessions)
  //but worst case you can cache the result yourself.
  somehowLoadUserFromLDAPByCN(cn, function(err, user) {
    done(err, {
     userId: user.cn,
     displayName: user.displayName
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Exaclty! But the problem is the I don't want to hit LDAP (resource intensive process) on every request. The same goes for a database. Why should I make a query on the DB on every request? That is exactly what I do not understand in the passport framework.

Comment: I can't recall if passport handles caching of the results of this function. You can check yourself by setting a breakpoint and seeing if it's being called when you're already authenticated. My assumption is that it doesn't (since passport has no idea if you want to cache these results. You can cache the result yourself in this function and only if cache miss, hit the LDAP query). The implementation of the cache is up to you (in-memory, redis etc...)

Comment: deserializeUser is called on every request even if you are already authenticated. I still cannot get what's the purpose of this functions. Why on Earth should I hit the auth system (DB, LDAP, facebook service) on every request?  Why should I cache the user profile in a DB if I can use the session to store username, email and those things?

Comment: Because sometimes your db contains additional info on that user (roles for example)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need an id and a display name, it's totally fine to keep them in session. You should only load the full user profile when you need more fields.